# Unable to change font in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-fonts

I was trying to change my vs code's font to `Roboto Mono`, I installed it from google fonts https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto+Mono?query=roboto+mono, and then i configured it in my vs code's settings, and instead of that im getting
[this font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAqsU.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly install your **font** and Try like that:

```
  "editor.fontFamily": "'Roboto Mono', monospace",
```

---

[image]

*Remember to restart VSCode!*

Comment: it did change the font, but i dont think so it is roboto mono- [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHnPL.png)

Comment: Install another one, you will see ... I use IBM Plex Mono and I am very satisfied ;-) Godd Luck ! Best regards !

Comment: okay i'll try with another font

Comment: Remember to Restart VSCode ;-)

Comment: You're Welcome ! I am happy for That ! :-D

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a necro of this thread, but for anyone else wondering why you can't install Roboto Mono or potentially other fonts like it, make sure you install the STATIC version of the font.

It seems like VSCode only supports static-type fonts instead of variable fonts, which by default Roboto Mono installs as. You can go into the 'static' folder in your Roboto_Mono.zip to install all files directly as static, remember to replace the old fonts.